# Laravel on Apache - wrong URLs

Tags: php, laravel, apache, centos8

I have deployed Laravel on Apache server, but got problem with wrong URLs.

The app directory is `/var/www/laravel`, but I only get access on it at:

```
http://127.0.0.1/laravel/public/index.php
```

On URL `http://127.0.0.1/laravel` I see tree of project files, on `http://127.0.0.1/laravel/public` I get message

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

What I want to achieve is to get access via `http://127.0.0.1/laravel` to my app.

**.htaccess** file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** v-host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1/laravel:80>
        ServerName 127.0.0.1
        ServerAlias localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
        <Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What I want mention is that I use CentOS 8 and I want to host more that 1 project on it.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This will listen for any IP address on port 80 including local host IP 127.0.0.1. Set up a different virtual host for access by domain name instead of IP address.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/main

        <Directory /var/www/main>

                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted

        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It cause that it is accessibly by `https://127.0.0.1/`. Is any chance to access it by `https://127.0.0.1/laravel` ? I want to host more than 1 app at this server. F.e. access to another app on `https://127.0.0.1/calculator`

Comment: Very easy to do if using different domains for each app. If you are not wanting to use domains for each app then you could listen on different ports instead of port 80 for each app or you could set up one main directory as a home page and sub diectorys for each app all on port 80

Comment: So, why I see tree of folders on `*/laravel` URL? "What do you mean one main directory as a home page"?

Comment: just create a folder with subfolders inside of it i.e. /var/www/main and then sub folders inside of that main folder i.e. /var/www/main/laravel and /var/www/main/calculator then set your document root as per the update above

Comment: OK, it works ok, but still with `http://127.0.1/laravel/public`. Still document tree on `*/laravel` :/

Comment: move your index.php out of the public folder and put it into the laravel folder

Comment: When I move it to `laravel` folder it cause an error : `http error 500`.. on URL `https://127.0.0.1/laravel` :/

Comment: log from `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:
`[Fri Aug 06 09:58:11.153105 2021] [autoindex:error] [pid 14498:tid 140683824482048] [client localhost] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/apps/laravel/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: http://127.0.0.1/laravel/public/login`

Comment: Your document root is still set to /var/www/apps/laravel/public . Have you actually restarted Apache so that the new document root /var/www/main is applied ?

Comment: Yes I've restarted it. `apps` is my `main` folder. I didn't change anything special.

Comment: ok so when you open http://127.0.0.1:80 in your web browser what do you see ?

Comment: `This page isn't working localhost 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request HTTP ERROR 500`.

Comment: ok and what is the apache error log saying when try access 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: Actually when I cat error_log it says nothing about this request now :/

Comment: is the apache server running

Comment: Yes it is running. Wait it logs after rr:
`[Fri Aug 06 11:31:49.497778 2021] [autoindex:error] [pid 16810:tid 140550791493376] [client localhost] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/apps/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

Comment: Maybe it is .htaccess problem now?

Comment: ok then enable apache error logging, restart apache so that config changes take effect,  try access local host again, then read the apache error log, there will have to be something in the error log if the apache server gives a 500 response

Comment: ht access file only contains configuration settings for the folder that it is in, there should be no ht access file in your main 'app' folder as its a new folder you just created

Comment: Other PHP sites works OK. It only cause error when I access this Laravel app so I assume it's .htaccess issue ...

Comment: I've got `.htaccess` at /var/www/apps/laravel/public.

Comment: yes but we were not talking about the /var/www/apps/laravel/public directory, your document root is set to /var/www/app so when you open 127.0.0.1:80 in the web browser you are opening the /var/www/app directory which has no ht access file

Comment: at `http://localhost/mailer/public` it says `403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.`

Comment: So, `index.php` is on `/var/www/apps/laravel` - root directory of project. No `.htaccess` in root dir, it's only on `/var/www/apps/laravel/public`.

Comment: you don't seem to be getting it, watch a few youtube videos on apache so that you get a basic understanding, your a bit too green.

Comment: I'm doing it like you told, but you still want logs which I gave you.